# What is syntax error of this?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I had written a small console calculator in python:

```
def calculator(num1=0, num2=0):
    conta = input("Type operation(+,x,/ or -:)")
    if (conta == "+"):
        print("Result:" + repr(num1) + " + " + repr(num2) + " is " + str(num1 + num2))
    elif (conta == "-"):
        print("Result:" + repr(num1) + " - " + repr(num2) + " is " + str(num1 - num2))
    elif (conta == "x"):
        print("Result:" + repr(num1) + " x " + repr(num2) + " is " + str(num1 * num2))
    elif (conta == "/"):
        print("Result: " + repr(num1) + " + " + repr(num2) + " is " + str(num1 / num2))
    else:
        print("Result:" + repr(num1) + conta + repr(num2) + " is Are you Joking?")

try:
    num1 = float(input("Type a number:"))
    num2 = float(input("Type a number:"))
    calculator(num1, num2)
except:
    print("Error.")
    exit()
```

It works properly in IDLE Shell. I put:

```
500.65 + 300 = 700.65
12 joke 12 = Are you Joking?
```

And then...When I load it from .PY file, It asks a number. I put it. Asks another. Put it. Asks for operation. I put one. The window closes.

Now I try to run it on Python console. Returns:

> SyntaxError in line 1 => Invalid Syntax.

So, what's wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is wrong indentation.

Also, you may want to use `operator` module for mapping user-defined strings with math operations:

```
import operator


def calculator(num1, num2, op):
    op_map = {'+': operator.add,
              '-': operator.sub,
              'x': operator.mul,
              '/': operator.div}

    if op not in op_map:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operation")

    return op_map[op](num1, num2)

num1 = float(input("Type a number:"))
num2 = float(input("Type a number:"))
op = input("Type operation (+,x,/ or -):")

print(calculator(num1, num2, op))
```

DEMO:

```
Type a number:10
Type a number:10
Type operation(+,x,/ or -):+
20.0

Type a number:10
Type a number:10
Type operation (+,x,/ or -):illegal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexander/job/so/test_mechanize.py", line 19, in <module>
    print calculator(num1, num2, op)
  File "/home/alexander/job/so/test_mechanize.py", line 11, in calculator
    raise ValueError("Invalid operation")
ValueError: Invalid operation
```

Comment: `raise "string"` is old, evil, deprecated, and gone in 3.x - just use `raise SomeAppropriateException("string")` (in this case, `ValueError` seems good).

Comment: @delnan omg, sorry, just a typo, thank you for pointing that.

Comment: You could avoid the `if` statement and do `try: return op_map[op](num1, num2); except KeyError: raise ValueError("Invalid operation")`

Answer (score 0):

for running a script in python read eval loop you should do something like

```
>>> import script
```